# Copiando um Datepicker para outro e incrementando um ano (jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Em um projeto meu, tenho dois campos configurados como `datepicker` (jQuery UI). Só o primeiro é editável (`InitialDate`). O segundo (`FinalDate`) deve ter o mesmo valor de `InitialDate` acrescido de um ano.

Se eu uso o seguinte código:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#InitialDate").change(function () {
            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $(this).val());
            d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
            $('#FinalDate').datepicker('setDate', d);
        });
    });
</script>
```

o script soma errado. A data fica com cinco dias a menos.

Pesquisando, descobri que eu tenho que modificar o código para algo assim:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#InitialDate").change(function () {
            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $(this).val());
            var year = parseInt(1, 10);
            d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + year);
            $('#FinalDate').datepicker('setDate', d);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Por que?

Comment: Não vejo dar errado http://jsfiddle.net/bkZ4V/

Comment: O segundo código é exatamente igual ao primeiro, afinal `parseInt(1, 10)` é sempre `1`. Qual a diferença?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código funciona, aparentemente o problema é com o formato do idioma, seu parse converte no formato `dd/mm/yy` enquanto o datepicker exibe no formato `mm/dd/yy`.

Veja um exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6H2Y/)

Procure pela tradução em [pt-BR](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/i18n/ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js?r=3004&spec=svn3034) do datepicker.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!